# why LSTM is performing poor than Simple Feed-forward Neural Network for Artificial time series data

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have an artificial data set. For 2 class classification problem

I have 2000 data instances with 500-time samples. All the data instances are vectors of zeros (500 zeros ) For the first 1000 data instances I added a small semi-circle in the middle around (200- 250) (They are called the targets). I then added noise to all of the data instances. (The other 1000 samples with no semi-circle are called the non-targets.)

The Task is to classify the Targets from the non-Targets.

I used LSTM for this task and I get 50% accuracy. The model is learning nothing.

Then I just used Fully Connected Layers and the accuracy was 99%….

I don't understand why LSTM didn't learn anything… What I am missing here

Comment: Welcome, user3602374! :) Maybe [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) platform is more suitable for your question.

Answer (score 0):

LSTMs are for time dependent data and their training process is usually a lot more complicated than Fully connected layers. Even though LSTMs suffer from gradient vanishing less than simple RNNs are still really hard to train.

Your problem does not really warrant a LSTM. LSTMS are useful for when the input or output sequence is of variable length. In your case this does not happen and the FNN works just fine.

Another use of LSTMs is when a timestep in the output depends probabilistically on the previous ones, which again is not your case.

To test an LSTM you could try predicting a next value on a sine wave for example, or try some translation, NLP, etc.